# Zero downtime deployment with Next.js

Tags: node.js, build, next.js, downtime

I have a Next.js application that I deploy by running

```
next build
next start
```

on the server.

While the build is happening, it clears out the files in the `.next` build folder, so for a few seconds if I try to use the app, it will give an error because the files don't exist:

```
MissingStaticPage [Error]: Failed to load static file for page: /reporting/letter_exhibits ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/polson/projects/JRP-Web-Tools/.next/server/pages/reporting/letter_exhibits.html'
```

Once I wait for the build to finish, the web app works as expected.

Is there a way to change the build process so that there will be no downtime during the build?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this simple strategy, although it won't guarantee "zero" downtime, but it would be much better than the current experience. Basically, you build your project into a `temp` folder, and then delete existing `.next` folder, and rename your `temp` folder as `.next`.

1. Add this to your `next.config.js` file:

```
distDir: process.env.BUILD_DIR || '.next',
```

2. Create a script with the following contents:

```
echo "Deployment starting..."

# install dependencies if any
yarn || exit

# set build folder to `temp` and build
BUILD_DIR=temp yarn build || exit

if [ ! -d "temp" ]; then
  echo '\033[31m temp directory does not exist!\033[0m'  
  exit 1;
fi

# delete `.next` folder
rm -rf .next

# rename `temp` folder to `.next`
mv temp .next

# run next start
next start

echo "Deployment done."
```

You should probably use a process manager like [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) for deployments though.

Comment: I saw this snippet in one blog but it didn't work. The key point was including dynamic distDir in next.config.js and setting it at build time. Great, thanks!